# How to obtain the text from a web site knowing it's contained within a <p> with certain CSS classes using Python?

Tags: python, html

I need to obtain the text from Twitter statuses URL's like:

**I know there's Twitter API, but I want to make as much queries as possible inside a loop (I got several ids stored) and querying Twitter API means code for dealing with limitations.**

https://twitter.com/CarolinaPadron/status/456540908368842752

Obtaining:

> Qué abuso el gol de Bale. Lleva el balón desde los 3/4 y le gana la
>   carrera a Bartra y con el defensa pegado, por debajo de Pinto 85'

https://twitter.com/daguilaraguilar/status/452557675956416512

Obtaining:

> I recommend Digital Ocean the MOST
>   https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=bbfb879343f7 …

https://twitter.com/CasillasWorld/status/447757078015139840

Obtaining:

> #HalaMadrid pic.twitter.com/61nJpT5TAO

The actual statuses (tweets) are within a `<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">`. However, several text like hashtags or links are contained within some other `html` nodes.

What approach is better for obtaining the site text and getting the actual text? I've heard about Beautiful Soup or Scrapy but I'm not sure about them.

Comment: Are you intentionally looking for a method that doesn't involve twitter's api?
Also I have used Beautiful Soup and remember finding it straightforward.

Comment: YES, I will edit my question. I want to make several queries over time and not to have to deal with more apps, threads and sleeping them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Twitter's API, or better yet, a python wrapper for Twitter's API, will probably result in cleaner code, however if you want to go with web scraping Beautiful Soup can definitely do the job.

Here is some quick sample code to get you started:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://twitter.com/CarolinaPadron/status/456540908368842752")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.findAll("p", "tweet-text")[0].text
```

[Beautiful Soup Documentation can be found here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Comment: Thanks. Trust me, they're over 200 000 tweets I want to retrieve, I've got the ids so I think I will be simpler to make it this way. I don't think my question is sooo bad after all